# Can a process adopt a grandchild as its child?

Tags: process, signals

Can a process pass the ownership of its children to its parent?

*Background*

Assume we have 3 processes: Grandparent, parent and child.

Parent spawns child and lives on (parent does not die).

Grandparent deals with processing when child dies, so it needs to be informed when a child dies. Getting the SIGCHLD would be excellent.

Comment: there's no way to do that portably; on linux, you may use `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1, 0, 0, 0)`, though it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: of course, the subreaper will become the "init" for all its descendants, not just its direct grandchildren.

Answer (score 3):

In general, parent processes are responsible for performing `wait()` on their children so that their children do not become zombies when they terminate.  If the parent process terminates before the child, then there must be some process to play the parent's cleanup role, again, preventing the children from becoming zombies.  By default, when a process terminates, any remaining children are reparented to the process with pid 1.

Linux does provide the `prctl` system call with the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` option.  According to the man page for `prctl`:

> `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` (since Linux 3.4)
>
> If `arg2` is nonzero, set the "child subreaper" attribute of the calling process; if `arg2` is zero, unset the attribute.
>
> A  subreaper  fulfills  the  role of `init(1)` for its descendant processes.  When a process becomes orphaned (i.e., its immediate parent terminates)  then  that  process  will  be reparented to the nearest still living ancestor subreaper.
>
> Subsequently, calls  to `getppid()` in  the  orphaned  process  will now return the PID of the subreaper
>   process, and when the orphan terminates, it is the subreaper process that  will  receive  a `SIGCHLD` signal and will be able to `wait(2)` on the process to discover its termination status.
>
> The setting of the "child subreaper" attribute is not  inherited  by
>                 children  created by `fork(2)` and `clone(2)`.  The setting is preserved
>                 across `execve(2)`.
>
> Establishing a subreaper process is  useful  in  session  management
>                 frameworks  where  a hierarchical group of processes is managed by a
>                 subreaper process that needs to be informed when  one  of  the  processes—for  example,  a  double-forked daemon—terminates (perhaps so
>                 that it can restart that process).  Some `init(1)`  frameworks  (e.g.,
>                 `systemd(1)`) employ a subreaper process for similar reasons.

That may be an option, but transitive descendants (not just the grandchildren) whose parents die will get reparented to the calling process.

Comment: But in my situation the parent does not die: It just wants to give up the child for adoption by the grandparent, while continuing living its own life.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  Unfortunately I do not believe there's anything that will enable you to do what you want to do.

Comment: @OleTange if you want to start a process and not have to wait for it, you should use a double fork, as already hinted to in that manpage snippet. There's also `SA_NOCLDWAIT`. But it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, and why the grandparent cannot just spawn the children itself.